# bash escaping and find command

Tags: command-line, bash, find, regex

I trying  to remove boring `\`-escaping from this command:

```
find . \( -name '*.mp3' -o -name '*.jpg' \) -print
```

by wrapping it in single quotes:

```
find . '( -name *.mp3 -o -name *.jpg )' -print
```

implying that arguments go straight to the `find` without any expansions.

However the output is different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
find . -name '*.mp3' -o -name '*.jpg' -print
```

Comment: It seems the closest way to get rid of \-escaping and make code cleaner. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: This only prints `*.jpg` files, the parentheses were there for a reason. If you remove `-print` it will work on most systems.

Answer (score 6):

You could also use regular expressions, which in my opinion make this more concise and gives you better control:

```
find . -regextype posix-egrep -iregex '.*(pdf|mp3)$'
```

This finds all files (or directories, unless you specify `-type f`) that end in pdf or mp3.

Answer (score 4):

```
find . '( -name *.mp3 -o -name *.jpg )' -print
```

This looks for all files in the directories named **`.`** and **`( -name *.mp3 -o -name *.jpg )`**, which is probably not what you intended.

Use the single quotes just for the round brackets:

```
find . '(' -name '*.mp3' -o -name '*.jpg' ')' -print
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! Is it possible to move a little bit further with it and remove that cumbersome escapings? Ideally to have as little quotes as possible?